# Custom url in my local site (problem with .htaccess file)

Tags: permissions, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress site and I want my url as: localhost/site/contact, for example. But, the system is displaying the follow:

```
You should update your .htaccess now.

If your .htaccess file were writable, we could do this automatically, but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select all.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /vogue/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /vogue/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But my wordpress has no .htaccess file. How can I locate it? My Ubuntu is 16.10.

Comment: If you don't have one, you create it.

Comment: create an .htaccess file at the root of the wordpress project

Comment: I create the file, but I can't save it in my wordpress. I think it is hidden.

Comment: `Ctrl + H` will toggle hidden files. If on the terminal, you can use `ls -a` to show them. It is okay that it's hidden.

Comment: rovr138, Yes, I used the command nautilus that allowed me post my .htaccess in my root site. And Ctrl + H to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: This will change default setting for PHP and thus is inadvisable. DO NOT DO THIS
The .htaccess file might be present in this path `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. It seems that you need to change the permission to this file to be written by you user.

Instead DO THIS

create an .htaccess file inside public_html folder of your wordpress project with the following lines

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /vogue/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /vogue/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will enable Apache's rewrite engine which is used to route different requests to a single file, which is essential for

Comment: You mean Apache

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Comment: akabhirav Yes.  I created a .htaccess in my desktop and opened the cmd, $ sudo nautilus, Copy and Paste in my root site and use Ctrl + H to show it. Thanks

Comment: glad it solved you problem